# MIPS Architecture : PC-relative addressing

Tags: computer-architecture

In case of branch Instructions such as `beq`, `bne`, we use PC-relative addressing. But I am not clear why it is said in most of the books that MIPS address(while calculating branch target) is actually relative to the address of following(or sequentially next) instruction (PC+4) as opposed to the current instruction (PC)?

Anybody please explain me. Thanks.